# Using Validator

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my website more search engine friendly.  In ding so I am trying to correct all warnings and errors listed in validator.w3.org.

One of the errors I am trying to correct is this:
The width attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

The code is:

```
    <table width="1100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"    align="center">
```

Can someone please provide an example of how this can be written using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
<table style="width: 1100px; text-align: center; border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
```

The right way would be to throw all the css into a separate file and link it via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

with the contents of style.css being:

```
table {
    width: 1100px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border: 0px; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**Update for multiple tables:**

```
<table id="table-one"> ... </table>
<table id="table-two"> ... </table>
```

in the css file:

```
table {
    text-align: center; 
    border: 0px; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table#table-one {
    width: 1100px; 
}

table#table-two {
    width: 980px; 
}
```

But if you're building your own sites, why not have a look at learning CSS? https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html-css is a good place to start.

Comment: Great! Thank you.  I created the css file and referenced that and the error is resolved.  However now I have another table on the same page:

Comment: <table width="980" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper">

Comment: How can I identify that table in the new css file?  In the original css file "wrapper" does exist, but thhere is no reference to the table.

Comment: There you go :).

Comment: It seems that no matter how I try this it does not work.

Comment: The css code I entered in the new css file is: 

        table { width: 1100px; text-align: center; border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; } 
        table { text-align: center; border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; } 
        table#table-one { width: 1100px; } 
        table#table-two { width: 980px; text-align: center; border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; }

Comment: <table id="table-one" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">

Comment: But is does not seem to reference "table-one" and the width is not specified, so the page just widens to the full length.

Comment: Hey Just me - would you mind setting up a JSFiddle with your code and sharing the link?

Comment: I think I found one of the reasons that this is causing some issues.  In the <table> on the file page the class="wrapper" is specified.

Comment: And when I check that reference in the main css file I see:

Comment: .wrapper{background:url(../images/bg-wrapper.png);}

Comment: So I have to keep that class, or change it to table-two and somehow add the table width requirements to it.